# Force application to use specific port on Fedora machine

Tags: linux, fedora, tcp

I have an application on my fedora machine that sends SIP TCP requests to the server. The application chooses a random source port to send the requests. Is there some way I can force the application to use a specific port (say 15000). Can I, maybe, block the application from using all other ports (and then it will have to choose a single source port)?

Note that I cannot change the code of the SIP application to use a predefined source port for the socket.

Comment: Why do you want to force a source port on the application? It sounds like an odd thing to do, and I suspect you've actually got some other problem that you are trying to solve.

Comment: I am trying to simulate a scenario where another machine receives SIP requests on a TCP connection with source port 5060. Hence, I need to force the SIP application to use 5060 as source port.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at the command line tool `socat` for simulating connections of all sorts (TCP, UDP, etc.).  There's a pretty extensive list of `socat` examples here, titled: [Examples for using socat (and filan)](https://stuff.mit.edu/afs/sipb/machine/penguin-lust/src/socat-1.7.1.2/EXAMPLES)
.

#### Example

```
$ socat - TCP:www.google.com:80 | head
GET /
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Date: Tue, 26 Aug 2014 13:22:09 GMT
Expires: -1
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
Set-Cookie: PREF=ID=31cc21da7fe930ae:FF=0:TM=1409059329:LM=1409059329:S=w1SmnrWq9nT2Ear-; expires=Thu, 25-Aug-2016 13:22:09 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.com
Set-Cookie: NID=67=PU8zfz-m-jwq17Jm2aixtDA1zi4H9JLpp6fXYAMS9V8xWpjBquGtng88Lf8wO-n8dUTjtneA2zon405GDYiqzsss_-HT44S5WgExWu7IrsEcqfBeguWB_oUEqlblJICL; expires=Wed, 25-Feb-2015 13:22:09 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.com; HttpOnly
P3P: CP="This is not a P3P policy! See http://www.google.com/support/accounts/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=151657 for more info."
Server: gws
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
2014/08/26 09:22:09 socat[28871] E write(1, 0x7f1c063ad9b0, 1418): Broken pipe
```

The above shows me connecting to a the web server at www.google.com on port 80, and sending it the request of `GET /`. This is a standard query that your browser would make if it were doing the same thing.

As to forcing your client to a particular port, it should be possible, we'd need to know the specifics of what app this is. Most of the time service daemons include a cli switch such as `-p 5000` or there's a line in their config files (if they have one) to do this.

I'd take a look at the usage of this particular tool to determine what capabilities it provides or take a peek at its man page if it has one.